# ViteJS websocket with https/2 over haproxy: Unexpected response code: 404

Tags: haproxy, http2, vite

A blank new vitejs project is created and started in a container

```
npm init @vitejs/app test --template vue
cd test
npm install
npx vite --https --port 9000
```

A haproxy configuration is in between the container's server and the browser. The global and the defaults haproxy.cnf sections seem to make no difference. They have the same results as with the default.

The relevant frontend backend definition is:

```
frontend port8443
    bind *:8443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/d250.hu.pem alpn h2,http/1.1

    default_backend default

backend default
    server port8443:my-test 10.110.24.2:8443 ssl verify none alpn h2,http/1.1
```

where 10.110.24.2 is the IP of the container.

Once ViteJS is opened in the browser it loads, but then fails.

Chrome reports

```
[vite] connecting...
client:200 WebSocket connection to 'wss://my-test.mydomain.com:8443/' 
failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404
(anonymous) @ client:200
```

Firefox reports a slightly different message

```
[vite] connecting...
Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at wss://my-test.mydomain.com:8443/.
```

Both hang for a while, or reload rapidly to make a websocket connection.
The error message is hard to catch. After the error it says polling to restart, and tries again.

A workaround is to disable http/2 by removing `alpn h2,http/1.1`

So, http1.1 works fine.
Vitejs without proxy works fine, and as a default it uses http/2.
Websockets in general work with both, http and http/2.

Is this now a bug in vitejs, or in the haproxy configuration?

Comment: I have the same issue with wss, it does not work with a secure local domain, 404.

Comment: I have a GitHub issue open: https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/1653

Answer (score 0):

I am struggling with the same problem, but haproxy docs says:

> ws { auto | h1 | h2 }
>
> This option allows to configure the protocol used when relaying websocket
> streams. This is most notably useful when using an HTTP/2 backend without the
> support for H2 websockets through the RFC8441.
>
> The default mode is "auto". This will reuse the same protocol as the main
> one. The only difference is when using ALPN. In this case, it can try to
> downgrade the ALPN to "http/1.1" only for websocket streams if the configured
> server ALPN contains it.
>
> The value "h1" is used to force HTTP/1.1 for websockets streams, through ALPN
> if SSL ALPN is activated for the server. Similarly, "h2" can be used to
> force HTTP/2.0 websockets. Use this value with care : the server must support
> RFC8441 or an error will be reported by haproxy when relaying websockets.
>
> Note that NPN is not taken into account as its usage has been deprecated in
> favor of the ALPN extension.
>
> See also "alpn" and "proto".

So by default websockets in haproxy seem to prefer same protocol as connected client (eg. h2) when initiating websocket connection.
So if your app requires to enforce HTTP/1.1 for websocket connections you should specify "ws h1" in your backend config (resulting in eg. "alpn http/1.1 ws h1").
You may need different backend definition for websockets connection.

Aditionally these options may be usefull:

> h2-workaround-bogus-websocket-clients
>
> This disables the announcement of the support for h2 websockets to clients.
> This can be use to overcome clients which have issues when implementing the
> relatively fresh RFC8441, such as Firefox 88. To allow clients to
> automatically downgrade to http/1.1 for the websocket tunnel, specify h2
> support on the bind line using "alpn" without an explicit "proto" keyword. If
> this statement was previously activated, this can be disabled by prefixing
> the keyword with "no'.

Also it's worth considering "timeout tunnel" for websocket backends. That overrides "timeout client" and "timeout server" for websocket tunnels, as well as "timeout client-fin" for half-closed connections.